# setState doesn't work as expected. It takes the initial state each time time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this code snippet, where I have to update the state and call the api each time the button gets click. The first time it works as expected but the next time it sets the endTime to initial time and sets the startTime with 2 hours prior to what was expected. My console log works perfectly but there is some issues while I am trying to setState. I have tried adding a callback function after each setState and also tried setting the state after the end of if-else but it doesn't show me the required result.

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component{
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
               timeData: {
                    endTime: moment(),
                    startTime: moment().subtract(2, 'h'),
                  
                },
                dropdownOption: '2HOURS'
    }
     this.callAPI= this.callAPI.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
                if (this.state.dropdownOption=== '2HOURS') {
                   this.callAPI();
                }         
            }
        
    onClick(){
                let time = {...this.state.timeData};
                let option;
                option = this.state.dropdownOption;
                if(option === '10hours'){
                time['endTime'] =timeData['startTime'];
                console.log('endTime', timeData['endTime'])
                time['startTime'] = timeData['endTime'].subtract(10, 'h');
                console.log('startTime', time['startTime'])
                this.setState({timeData: time}, this.callAPI())
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see where the state is initialised, better yet a reproducible example of your problem, the issue could be in one of your component lifecycle methods, but we can't tell just by looking that the supplied code snippet.

Comment: I have updated my code @RicardoSanchez

Comment: It could also be useful to see what's inside `callAPI`.
Anyway, I see at your last line that your call the function you pass as callback of setState, it's unusual. Have you tried this way instead  `this.setState({timeData: time}, this.callAPI)` ? in order to call `callAPI` only when setState has been resolve and not before calling setState.

Comment: You are not using the state values `time['endTime'] =timeData['startTime'];` change it to `time['endTime'] = this.state.timeData['startTime'];` same for the other calls

Comment: @Peterrabbit I havent done anything in callAPI yet but just making sure that correct data is getting passed there. With the console that I added there it doesnt seems. Tried calling onlu this.callAPI but it doesnt provide right data.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez yea I tried to take the data from state but I am just getting the previous end data and not the new one.

Comment: Sorry, it cannot get clearly what you are trying to do. In your example, indeed, `timedata` seems undefined...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do but, you should take care of the fact that `setState` is asynchronous, so if you call `callAPI` the same moment you call `setState` it's normal that `callAPI`doesn't get the updated state. (I think I understand that this is the way you are trying to use your `callAPI`).

Here is a suggestion of implementation, at least to get it clearer:

```js
class ButtonComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeData: {
                endTime: moment(),
                startTime: moment().subtract(2, 'h'),
            },
            dropdownOption: '2HOURS',
        };
        this.callAPI= this.callAPI.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.dropdownOption=== '2HOURS') {
            this.callAPI();
        }         
    } 
    callAPI() {
       console.log("updated state", this.state.timedata)
    }

    onClick() {
        const timeData = {...this.state.timeData};
        const option = this.state.dropdownOption;
        if(option === '10hours') {
            // I quite don't get the way you want to update your state so this might need to be adapted.
            timeData.endTime = timeData.startTime;
            timeData.startTime = moment();

            // this.callAPI willl be called as soon as the state update is resolved by setState so the new state will be available inside callAPI.
            this.setState({timeData}, this.callAPI);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have a button on clicking of the button, it resets the data i.e, the endTime gets updated with the new startTime and the startTime gets updated with a time 10 hours before the startTime. On every click the startTime and endTime should change and a POST api request should be made with the new start and end times. While I am trying to console log the startTime and endTime, I could see the time displayed correctly but after I try to set the times in setState, the set data is displayed incorrectly.  Tried the above method but still facing same issue.

Comment: Ok. But I don't see where you are setting the new startTime ? In this (and so also in my example), it's always the same data defined at start with `moment()` replacing each other indefinitely.
Maybe you should recall `moment()` for each click ?

Comment: Ohh so we need to set the startTime again? Will it not get set once I call the setState method later? Can you help me with an example of how to do it!

Comment: I updated my answer, I think it sticks more to what you want (if I got it well...).

Comment: @Peterrabit, here we are only taking the current time for the endTime. We need to set the endTime with the new startTime. For eg. If endTime is 10:00pm and startTime is 12:00am on clicking the button, the endTime should be 12:00am and the startTime should be 2:00pm

Comment: It's still quite unclear for me, but I updated my answer. You should likely adapt it to make it stick to what you want. But the point remains the same regarding the state resolution..